# Whileloop re create structure after every 6 div

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, repeat

I want to repeat  after every 6  but I have no idea why this structure not repeating in a way I want.

Here is my code

```
<?php
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=12' );

$counter = 0;           

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

if($counter % 6 == 0) :
    echo '<div class="row margin-top20">';
endif; ?>           

    <div class="two columns">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> 
    </div>
<?php
if($counter % 6 == 0) :
        echo '</div>';
    endif;
endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Stupid question on my part, perhaps - but where's the counter increment?

Comment: ah you are right... I admin it's really a stupid question.. so involved in some other stuffs so didn't realize.. thanks for noticing me.. :).. my own vote for you ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not incremented the counter.

Increment the counter like this:

```
<?php
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=12' );

$counter = 1;           

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
if($counter % 6 == 0) :
    echo '<div class="row margin-top20">';
endif; ?>           

    <div class="two columns">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> 
    </div>
<?php
$counter++;
if($counter % 6 == 0) :
        echo '</div>';
    endif;
endwhile; ?>
```